# How to make alasql work in my asp.net web application work?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alasql

i have been following an online example available at fiddle. It clearly shows how to query javascript objects using sql queries. this is the exact situation for me.

However, the problem comes in when i try to run this fiddle example in my asp.net project.

as per the below link 
[https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/install]

i have tried adding :

```
<script src="alasql.js"></script>
```

in the head tag along with its js files in my project

I also added(for another try)

also

```
<script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
```

But upon debugging the project i get the below error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: alasql is not defined

and, when i view page source no such link comes up which i provided in my html page head tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need one of two solutions.

1. Have `alasql.min.js` in the same folder as your html is served from

or

2. Include the script with

   ```
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.7/alasql.min.js"></script>
   ```